# How to access a Friend method from a Module or Class Web File

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, access-modifiers

I am developing a VB.NET ASP.NET web site.  I would like to be able to restrict access of one of my methods that is being used across all of my pages to Friend.

When I do this, whether in a Module or in a VB Class Web File (in my App_Code project folder), I am unable to see it.  I get the error [method] is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.

From all of my research it appears this is because the bin is arranged into a number of distinct DLLs - a couple for the App_Web_#### and one for the App_Code.

I tried moving this file out of the App_Code folder and putting it at the level of the rest of the files (same level as pages), but I was not able to reference it from there.

I looked into specifying the following at the top of the Module/Class, but since the App_Web_#### seems to be indeterminate, I wouldn't be able to use something reliably.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
<Assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("AssemblyB")>
```

EDIT: I am trying to do this in Visual Studio 15

There must be a way to reference a Friend method from a Module or class file.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

`InternalsVisibleTo` must be located in the assembly that contains the `Friend` methods that you want to expose, and it must name the assembly that you want to expose those members to.

Having said that, `InternalsVisibleTo` cannot be restricted to a single member: it's an all or nothing sort of thing.

What is happening for you is that your code is being split into two different assemblies, and you don't know the name of the second assembly; it's generated at compile time. If that name remains constant between builds, you might be able to determine it by inspecting the assembly at run time (through the Object Browser). Once you know the assembly name, you can use that to properly expose the internal members.

Comment: We generally sign our assemblies, in which the `PublicKey` of the consuming assembly is required as well. Eg, `<Assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("My.Consuming.Friend, PublicKey=00743090048...")>`. You'll find that VS will auto-insert this if you hold your mouth right.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Yeah, the problem is, there are two DLLs for the code behind.  They are named with the format App_Web_#### where the suffix is a combination of letters and numbers.  It is unclear how this suffix is generated, and each time I go to compile or publish, the suffixes change.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger That's unfortunate. You may be able to work around the issue by creating another class library assembly with a fixed name, and refactor your solution so that the code currently located in App_Code is located in this new assembly. In that way, the assembly name doesn't change between builds. It'll take some work, but if you preserve the namespace names, it shouldn't be too challenging, and should solve your problem handily.

Comment: Ok, I might give that a try as time allows.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/friend) Microsoft reference page:

*Code in other classes, structures, and modules that are compiled to the same assembly can access all the Friend elements in that assembly.*

Compiled Class Libraries (aka DLLs) are considered stand-alone assemblies, so you'll have to declare elements you want to be accessible by external code - even in the same application - as `Public` and add a  reference to the Library to that code.

Although it seems like you should be able to access `Friend` elements from other assemblies within the same application, I don't think the compiler can differentiate the same application consuming the Library and a third-party app doing so. I'd be interested to hear what others might have to say about this.

Comment: Friend members in other assemblies can be accessed if they are properly exposed using the `Assembly:InternalsVisibleToAttribute` in the `AssemblyInfo.vb` or `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

Comment: @MikeHofer Ok, I stand corrected, and have learned something to try, as all of our apps are split between various assemblies as well. I'll post back if there're any issues with this method.

Comment: @MikeHofer Confirmed. You can either add the directive to the class, etc code file(s), etc or to the `AssemblyInfo` file (my preference). Worth the down vote to find out about this as it will help obfuscate (ish) some of our code. Thanks.